# weird behavior with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable, acts-as-taggable-on

### Edit

The instructions on Github instruct you to use the gemcutter source for the gem. Currently, this installs version 2.0.5 which includes the bug I've detailed below.

@Vlad Zloteanu demonstrates that 1.0.5 does not include the bug. I have also tried with 1.0.5 and confirm that the bug does **not** exist in this version. People struggling with acts_as_taggable_on and owned tags on 2.x, rollback and wait for a fix..

---

For some reason, tags aren't showing up on a taggable object when an tagger is specified.

#### testing the post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  belongs_to :user
end

>> p = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1, ...>
>> p.is_taggable?
=> true
>> p.tag_list = "foo, bar"
=> "foo, bar"
>> p.save
=> true
>> p.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 1, name: "foo">, #<Tag id: 2, name: "bar">]
```

#### testing the user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  has_many :posts
end

>> u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, ...>
>> u.is_tagger?
=> true
>> u.tag(p, :with => "hello, world", :on => :tags)
=> true
>> u.owned_tags
=> [#<Tag id: 3, name: "hello">, #<Tag id: 4, name: "world">]
```

#### refresh the post

```
>> p = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1 ...>
>> p.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 2, name: "bar">, #<Tag id: 1, name: "foo">]
```

Where's the `hello` and `world` tags? Miraculously, if I modify the database directly to set `tagger_id` and `tagger_type` to `NULL`, the two missing tags will show up. I suspect there's something wrong with my `User` model? What gives?

---

#### EDIT

Even stranger:

```
Post.tagged_with("hello")
#=> #<Post id: 1, ...>
```

It finds the post! So it can read the tag from the database! How come it's not showing up with `Post#tags` or `Post#tag_list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated your project, using exactly the same classes.

This is my result:

```
>> Post.create
=> #<Post id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36", updated_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36">
>> p = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36", updated_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36">
>> p.is_taggable?
=> true
>> p.tag_list = "foo, bar"
=> "foo, bar"
>> p.save
=> true
>> p.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 1, name: "foo">, #<Tag id: 2, name: "bar">]
>> User.create
=> #<User id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-18 09:17:02", updated_at: "2010-05-18 09:17:02">
>> u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-18 09:17:02", updated_at: "2010-05-18 09:17:02">
>> u.is_tagger?
=> true
>> u.tag(p, :with => "hello, world", :on => :tags)
=> true
>> u.owned_tags
=> [#<Tag id: 3, name: "hello">, #<Tag id: 4, name: "world">]
>> p = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36", updated_at: "2010-05-18 09:16:36">
>> p.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 1, name: "foo">, #<Tag id: 2, name: "bar">, #<Tag id: 3, name: "hello">, #<Tag id: 4, name: "world">]
```

Therefore, I can not replicate your bug. I've tried it with both mysql and sqlite.

This is from my env file:

`config.gem "mbleigh-acts-as-taggable-on", :source => "http://gems.github.com", :lib => "acts-as-taggable-on`"

This is my gem version:

```
gem list | grep taggable
mbleigh-acts-as-taggable-on (1.0.5)
```

Can you post your gem version? Can you try to upgrade your gem? What DB are you using?

If it doesn't work, can you also post the output from `tail -f log/development.log` ?

EDIT: I'm using Rails 2.3.5

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but I will check later this evening. I'll get back to you :)

Comment: you were right. I had to go out of my way to specify an older version of this gem. The readme on github instructs me to use the gemcutter source and it installs 2.0.5. Talk about major bug...

Answer (score 0):

mbleigh released a commit that resolve this problem.
To obtain ALL the tags you can use owner_tags_on :

```
p = Post.first
p.owner_tags_on(nil, :tags )
```

This is the commit: http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/commit/3d707c25d45b5cc680cf3623d15ff59856457ea9

bye,
Alessandro DS